# Slow performance on Docker Containers as a Compile and Run Sandbox

Tags: compilation, docker, sandbox

I am trying to use the following github project to allow users to compile and run programs online.

https://github.com/remoteinterview/compilebox

It came out to be a straight out of the box solution for a project and the overall code and configurations are very easy to understand and configure.

However I am now getting a performance issue.

Everything works good and fast If I run a single program from a single browser at a time. But If go to a little more real condition where multiple users(maximum 30) are trying to run piece of "Hello World" Java code at a single instance, the response time the containers increases up to 2-3 minutes and the many users.

I was wondering If I am missing some configurations tweaks of docker or it the hardware level limitation?

Following is my Hardware Configuration
Processor : Core-i5 3.0 Ghz
Ram : 12 Gb Total (On and average 8GB Free)

The CPU Load is about 50% while Running 5 containers.
Controlling CPU share and setting to 512 only makes it worst.

Comment: Have you tried measuring CPU usage on the docker host and on each container during the peak usage interval?

Comment: Yes I have done that on host by running top command, it shows ~50%+ of CPU used.

Comment: My next step would be to enforce CPU limits per container to isolate workloads.

Comment: Already done and set each container to have 512 CPU share, it just make the things worst.

Comment: You should mention these steps that you've already undertaken directly in question text. This would have saved my time.